# Can a simple cordless screwdriver have neither a clutch nor a variable speed?

Tags: tools, powertools, screwdriver

For some time now my corded 3/8″ drill [doubled](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1428/115116) as a screwdriver when I had too many screws ahead of me.

This works just fine. I just needed to stop before a screw was seated, and used a manual screwdriver to adjust by feel the pressure (torque) until the head of the screw was at just the right depth.

I would now like to spare my wrist and go for the convenience of a cordless screwdriver. I realize that the nicer models have a torque setting. But since I will anyway complete my tool collection with a precise torque wrench for bicycle work, I'm now aiming for the most simple electric screwdriver, [one](https://www.makita.ca/index2.php?event=tool&id=3136) that does *not* have a torque setting.

Since it lacks the [VSR](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/16223/115116) designation, does this mean that I will still need to worry about stripping the head of a screw or of driving a screw far too much into the wood? Doesn't the mere fact that it's labeled a "screwdriver" [mean](https://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/clutches-torque-and-you/) that it must have a clutch?

Another important feature that I might be losing when going from a drill to a simple screwdriver is that even the simplest electric drills have a variable-speed bit, through a pressure-sensitive trigger. Do simple screwdrivers suddenly jump from zero to their max rpm? This jump is alright (and expected) on a drill, but lacking vari-speed means that using such a tool as a screwdriver would be rather tricky. I would still need to turn manually the beginning and end of each screw.

It's easy to [say](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16221/115116) *"Drills are for drilling, drivers are for driving."* In practice there are models on the market labeled "drill driver", which suggests that the line is quite blurry. If anything, a "driver" must by definition have variable speed; no?

**This is a comment to the answer by "manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact"**

But making the jump from a power screwdriver to a full-blown drill/driver requires understanding another issue.

With an ordinary (non-powered) screwdriver, we're used to a format like this.

[image: pen-like power screwdriver]

There are on the market power screwdriver that accommodate both styles of holding the tool. They switch from L-shape to I-shape.

[image: power screwdriver that changes from I-shape to L-shape]

The more serious drill/drivers seem to be made in just the L-shape format. They cannot be held like a pen-screwdriver.

[image: drill-like power screwdriver]

Are you then saying that someone who "makes the jump" will not end up missing the pen-like (or I-shape format) for some usage scenarios?

Comment: Do you have budget for an impact driver? They are far and away better than any drill for driving screws.

Comment: The 'screwdriver' has a very low no load RPM, almost slower than a very slow turning drill.

Comment: Product recommendations or shopping advice is off topic. If you don’t want to use the torque setting most have just set it to the max.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  A while back I had what I thought was an impact drill. It was a drill with an extra button. You click the button, and the bit hammers. The sort of thing you need to drive into a bit of concrete. Maybe that's really called a hammer drill. Does an "impact driver" offer a different functionality?

Comment: @EdBeal I know that product recommendations are off topic, as the products can disappear from the market on short notice and the answers would quickly become irrelevant. I don't actually want a product recommendation. What someone recommends is unlikely to be on sale everywhere around the world anyway. But are you also saying that there is no common way to identify features? Do the terms "impact drill" and "cordless screwdriver" mean different things, depending on jurisdiction and (gasp) on manufacturer?

Comment: @Sam -- what you're referring to as an impact drill is called a hammer drill on these shores. I'm talking about an 'impact driver'. https://www.dewalt.com/products/power-tools/impact-drivers-and-wrenches/20v-max-xr-14-3speed-impact-driver-kit-20ah/dcf887d2

Comment: And @EdBeal, I know what you're saying about shopping, but this is a category/ 'best tool for the job' question in my mind.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Could you provide one more hint? Which one of the qualifiers: very high torque ("_up to 1825 in-lb_"); "_compact design_" "_multi-speed_", as well as ultra-low speed—or "_Precision Drive™_", and "_more runtime_" make it an "impact" driver?

Comment: @SolarMike Good catch. I meant to say "clutchless". Fixed.

Comment: A "simple screwdriver" has a bit at one end and a handle at the other. You can turn it as fast or as slow as you can manage by hand, and with as much or as little force as you can manage by hand. It has no battery, nor cord, and no motor.

Comment: This is a decent introduction to impact driver versus drill: https://www.bobvila.com/articles/what-is-an-impact-driver/ ... (tldr: impact driver is fundamentally a different tool than a drill)

Comment: I have a 1/4” impact driver dewalt, Milwaukee and the orange box store all have a similar tool. yes I have all 3 not for drilling concrete but driving screws,or drilling. they spin really fast with no load as the force increases they start “hitting” and slow down( just like a impact gun In automotive shops)  I also have drill bits and spade style drill bits that work in this driver. a hammer drill actually hammers as it spins to break up the rock in the concrete. Hammer drills would be the worst option for trying to drive screws, I have a 3 speed drill with a clutch, drill or hammer option .

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I see. The most revealing part is this: "_you’ll find using an impact driver is easier on your hand and wrist_". Whenever the cordless screwdriver encounters resistance, my wrist would still take a beating. But an impact driver would apply sudden torque and use the inertia of the driver/drill to counter the rotation, sparing my wrist.

Comment: You won't miss the "pen" shape. At all.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That's also my hunch. We like the pen-shape because all screwdrivers are manufactured that way, but when we really have the option—say with a T-handle over a hex/Allen wrench—we don't think twice and we enjoy the ease of applying pressure and torque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd seriously consider making the jump from "just a power screwdriver" to a full-blown drill/driver. There are a *lot* of them out there. My recommendation is to pick one of the major house brands (e.g., Ryobi from Home Depot) or a major brand (e.g., Dewalt) so that you can start with a drill/driver, one battery and charger (that's the typical starter pack) and then later when you need other tools you can add them without needing additional batteries or chargers.

The sweet spot for the last few years has been 18V - 20V. Lower voltage doesn't give you as much power and higher is, IMHO, overkill for "ordinary users". A decent drill/driver is going to be a bit heavier than a simple power screwdriver, but a *lot* more powerful, and of course usable as a drill as well. All the ones I am familiar with have decent variable speed & torque.

Comment: Instead of adding a comment here with a clarification, I updated the body of the question. Please read under _comment to the answer by "manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact"_.

Comment: @Sam unfortunately, your quest for clarification _should_ have been here as a comment, and your update to the question makes it too broad _and_ opinionated. _Some_ people may miss the "pen" shape, while others may not.

Answer (score 1):

When navigating the cordless drivers/drills on the market, there are a several factors to consider.

We assume that, in this day and age, not to mention COVID, you're shopping online and don't actually see the tool until it's delivered and you opened the box.

- **The voltage** Is it a 4V unit, a 12V unit, or a 20V unit? The torque you obtain from the first (<50 in.lb, say) will be in a completely different range than the torque you get from the last (1800 in.lb is not unusual).
- **The weight** Does it weight 400g/0.5lbs or 1.8kg/4lbs? The first will be very easy to manipulate with one hand.
- **The size** Is it small enough to fit into the space you need?
- **Impact** If it carries that label, it means that it can apply a sudden torque—helpful for tougher materials.
- **Hammer** That label indicates that it can apply a sudden pressure (and produces a very loud noise). Only use this if you're driving into concrete. You will need a properly labeled bit.
- **RPM** If listed, an rpm of 300 qualifies the unit as a driver (a screwdriver). An rpm of 1200 or more makes it a drill. Some units function as both.
- **Clutch** If a ring with markings indicating numbers (say from 1 to 12) is present, then it's a proper driver and will be less likely to strip your screws/bolts, not to mention that it will be less likely to damage your wood or other material.
- **Brushless Motor** The lifetime of this type of motor far exceeds the classical motor design. If you're an amateur, not a professional, this is way beyond what you need. If you use a brushed-motor tool every other weekend, it will still last you a lifetime.
- **Ball bearings** This is one part of what you pay for if you buy "pro" labeled tools. You can abuse the unit knowing that the ball bearing will take the load just fine. Again, this is an overkill feature if you're an amateur.
- **Energy stored in battery** Does the unit come with a 1.0 A⋅h battery or a 5.0 A⋅h battery? You will be able to use the latter longer before running out of charge.

The line between a driver and a drill is (no longer) very well defined. The factors above will determine whether the tool is one or the other. But the short version is that a (screw)driver does not necessarily mean that it has either a clutch or variable speed. It may simply mean that it is light (one-hand usage) and small (fits into tight spaces).

Comment: When buying online, the #1 thing is to make sure you're not buying cheap Chinesium or counterfeits of the real McCoy. Even "sold by: Amazon" is no longer reliable due to commingling.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use: A [speed wrench](http://www.sears.com/craftsman-speeder-wrench-1-4-in-drive/p-00904281000P) and a [bit holder](http://amzn.to/1VmaSGs).  You can press as hard as needed, you get crazy leverage, and it doesn't wear out your wrists.  Tremendous torque and you can stop on a dime.

Also, it lets me hold the drill back for use *as a drill* for pre-drilling holes.

[image]
[source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Speed_wrench.jpg)

Comment: Lol... You're right. No fear I'd hurt my wrists after a few dozen screws using this tool. I'm just worried that, with both hands occupied, I'd need to apply a bit of pressure and would end up with blisters on my chin.

Comment: @Sam Oh well, they make them with different handles. My downforce mostly comes from the hand on the end handle, but I have been known to use my chin :)

Comment: @Sam If you get problems with the bit camming out, you might want to consider using Torx-head screws.